# In my comment form, how do I move the "notify me of follow-up comments" box above the "post comment" button?

Tags: comment-form, notifications

I'm using a plugin called "Subscribe to Comments Reloaded". It actually features an option to do exactly what I want: "If this option is enabled the subscription box will be above the submit button in your comment form." The problem is, when I enable it, the "notify me" box (and accompanying text) disappears completely instead of moving. I'm attaching a screen capture of what my comment form currently looks like.[image: my comment form]

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure nothing get happens with some JS code when "Notify me" button is checked?

This option says :

> If this option is enable the subscription box will be above the submit
>   button in your comment form. Use this when your theme is outdated and
>   using the incorrect WordPress Hooks and the checkbox is not displayed.

I suggest to you to check the call of your comments template and if an update is available for your theme.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have to admit I don't really understand it.

Comment: I'm not concerned with whether the "notify me" box works. I just want to move it.